# R - Convert variables in data frame to a factor

Tags: r

I have created a data frame from a SQL query using the RODBC package.  I have a separate single column data frame in which each rows contains a name of a column in the main data set that I would like to convert to a factor.

This is the logic though the syntax is obviously wrong.

```
for(c in 1:length(df.ToFactor$IV)-0) {

 VarToFactor<- as.character(df.ToFactor$IV[c])
 df.dataset[VarToFactor]<-factor(df.HRV[VarToFactor])

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subtraction of zero from a vector of integers doesn't make much sense. I suspect you may wnat to use the `[[<var-name>]]` construction:

```
for(c in 1:length(df.ToFactor$IV) ) {

 VarToFactor<- as.character(df.ToFactor[["IV"]][c])
 df.dataset[[VarToFactor]]<-factor(df.HRV[[VarToFactor]])
      }
```

I also changed the "$" operation to the equivalent "[[" operation just because it's safer in programming, although I think in a for-loop at an interactive session it would not cause problems. In addition to the ?Extract page where the detail of "[[" and "[" are described one can find useful information in the "R Inferno" by Patrick Burns. This particular area is covered on p 52.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works.  Is there a reference I can read about the [[varname]] operation.  Clearly I need to understand that better.

Comment: ?Extract (typed at you console.) Studying that page requires a bit of work, I will admit. A key point is recognizing that the "$" operator does not evaluate the variable name passed to it while "[[" will do so when it is not surrounded by quotes. So a$b is the same as a[["b"]], but '$' can never be used to do what a[[x]] will do if x="b".

Comment: For simplicity you could iterate over names: `for (VarToFactor in as.character(df.ToFactor[["IV"]]) ) {df.dataset[[VarToFactor]]<-factor(df.HRV[[VarToFactor]])}`

Comment: @Marek: If simplicity were the goal, it would be hard to beat: df.dataset <- data.frame( lapply( df.HRV[[ as.character(df.ToFactor) ]], factor))

Comment: I meant to use "[" instead of "[[" in that expression but missed my 5 minute window.